# How to make a moving chart in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I`m designing a program for some project and here is my question:

If I have a set of X , Y and time in excel
and I want a chart when I click some button it will move according to the time (more like an animation of the line )

I need the name of the function or how to make this happen.
Thank you.

Comment: Is this sort of thing what you mean ? : https://excelcharts.com/animation-interaction-and-dynamic-excel-charts/

Comment: if I have a series for x and y for 10 seconds ( for example ), how can I make a chart start from 0 seconds until it reach the last point ( like animation )

Answer (score 0):

Define the ranges for the chart series using the offset function and include a variable in the row-offset field. For example, if you always want to include 10 rows of data that moves, define a series in column A as:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,Start,0,10,1)
```

Define another cell as `Start` and put the value 0 in there. With each increment of value Start, the range of 10 values will move down by one. If you do this for both the x-series an y-series, then used these defined names in the chart, the range of values displayed in the chart will be controlled by the Start value.

Note that when you put named ranges into a chart, they need to be qualified by the sheet name, e.g.: `=Sheet1!XSeries`

You can either update Start manually, or link it to a Spin control so that when you click up or down, in increases/decreases the value in the cell by 1. Or you can add commandbuttons with VBA to increase, decrease and reset the value.